# Is there a way to specify x y and z limits in matplotlib plots in one command instead of 3 separate lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I am developing a program that needs to automatically switch from 2D to 3D plots in matplotlib. So I am looking for a way to not have many if statements to decide between 2 and 3d

I have looked at postings here as well as matplotlib documentation page and I didnt find anything

currently the plot axes limits are set using

```
ax.set_xlim(minvals[0],maxvals[0])  
ax.set_ylim(minvals[1],maxvals[1])
```

then if it is 3D I have a separate list

```
ax.set_xlim3d(min_vals[0],max_vals[0])
ax.set_ylim3d(min_vals[1],max_vals[1])
ax.set_zlim3d(min_vals[2],max_vals[2])
```

It seems logical to have a way to have something like  ax.set_lims(min_vals, max_vals) whether for 2d or 3d. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `.set(**kwargs)` like this:

```
ax.set(**{'xlim3d': [min_vals[0],max_vals[0]], \
          'ylim3d': [min_vals[1],max_vals[1]], \
          'zlim3d': [min_vals[2],max_vals[2]]})
```

Usually when you want to set a property `xxxx` with `.set_xxxx()`, you use:

```
ax.set_xxxx(some_value)
```

With `.set(**kwargs)` I explain above, when `.set_xxxx(some_value)` is added, it becomes:

```
ax.set(**{'xlim3d': [min_vals[0],max_vals[0]], \
          'ylim3d': [min_vals[1],max_vals[1]], \
          'zlim3d': [min_vals[2],max_vals[2]], \
          'xxxx': some_value})
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the explanation. I am a newbie so how do I accept the answer

Comment: @arunsrinivasa  To accept an answer:

Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.
Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just define a function:

```py
def set_lims(ax, minvals, maxvals):
    ax.set_xlim(minvals[0], maxvals[0])  
    ax.set_ylim(minvals[1], maxvals[1])
    if len(minvals) == 3:
        ax.set_zlim3d(minvals[2], maxvals[2])
```